# Access provider from another provider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am using the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) implementation by Remi Rousselet/dash-overflow.net.

I have one provider called `AuthProvider` that handles everything in terms of user authentication. As part of this the provider stores the *access token* used to make API requests.

I want to implement the logic to access the REST API in another provider (`ProductProvider`). In `ProductProvider` I need the *access token* since I have to include it with every request made to the REST API.

Furthermore I need to be able to trigger the `refreshAccessToken` method (in the `AuthProvider`) from the `ProductProvider`. This would be used if the *access token* expired and I need to refresh it prior to making the API request.

What is the best practice to access the methods/fields of one provider from another provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Provider 3.0.0 you have a ProxyProvider that is designed for this use-case.

You can create a ProxyProvider that takes an AuthProvider and return a ProductProvider. Every time the  authProvider  changes you will get a new ProductProvider that use the new AuthProvider. That  way

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for.